# change db configuration using a dropdown box

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database

Is there any way that I can change the database that I am hitting depending on maybe some dropdown box that I select?

Right now I have made a dashboard which basically connects to the db at the time of running server using a configuration file. But I want it to be dynamic so that from the UI itself if a particular option is chosen, then I get to connect to that db and show all the information for that db itself.

Comment: Please show us your own attempts

Comment: Oh yes, you can definitely do that. Other question? :)

Comment: @Wndrr..not much efforts till now.just brainstorming as to how it can be done.one way that i could think is to run different instances of that dashboard and then using ui redirect to a url depending upon the selected option since the options in my ui are limited to two or three. but that doesn't look very effective to me. so just brainstorming what could be a more effective way.

Comment: What about editing the configuration file as the options change in order to target the different databases?